# How To Create A Stored Procedure That return a Random Number If Not Exist In The Table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I Want To Create A Stored procedure That return A Random Number Between (11111,99999)

### Provided that the Number Should Not Exist In The Table

I use This complicated Function to Do that But I Need To Convert it to Stored Procedure

```
    Function GiveRandomStudentNumber() As String
s:
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim st_num As String = rnd.Next(11111, 99999)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select count(0) from student where st_num = " & st_num,con)
        dd.con.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        dd.con.Close()
        If count <> 0 Then
            GoTo s
        Else
            Return st_num
        End If
    End Function
```

this Function Is Works But I need To Convert it To Stored Procedure ..

Thanks In Advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Select_RandomNumber] 
(
@Lower INT, --11111-- The lowest random number
@Upper INT --99999-- The highest random number
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT (@Lower < @Upper) RETURN -1

    --TODO: If all the numbers between Lower and Upper are in the table,
    --you should return from here
    --RETURN -2

    DECLARE @Random INT;
    SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)

    WHILE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE randCol = @Random)
    BEGIN

        SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
    END

    SELECT @Random
END
```

Comment: Thank you , But I forget Some Thing

1- The Stored Procedure Should Not Return A Minus Number .
(When I Execute it It Gives Me **-23763**)
2- The Number Returned Must be 5 Digits 
(When I Execute it It Gives Me **217**)

Comment: If you pass at least `10000` for @Lower it will return 5 digit no. This is more like a `function rather than a stored procedure`.

Comment: -1 You should test your solution when all but one student IDs are used :).

Comment: @RemusRusanu didn't you read the --TODO: in the body of the sp? I have clearly mention that.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I don't get why 1 exception, but I have moved the commet before the WHILE. I think it makes more sense returning before getting into the WHILE loop at all..

Comment: If all the student IDs between `@Lower` and `@Upper` are taken, except one, you're caller is going to have to wait quite a while until the random number generator happens to hit exactly the one not used. The procedure will return fast for the first ID generated, and then it will degrade as the number of 'free' IDs is reduced. This will never work in the real world. You need to choose one random number *from the ones available*, not roll the dice ad-nauseam until you hit a free one...

Comment: @RemusRusanu, First of all, I don't know what user is doing before executing the procedure. `Lower and Upper` values can be optimised numbers. All the logic in the world is not in this sp for sure. User has accepted the answer. I guess that is what he needed and he is open for improvements as required... Also Id checking table may have constant number of records as well (OP has said nothing about it). So in that case there won't be any performance degrade.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table of student IDs. Fill it up with IDs between X and Y. Every time you want to use an ID, remove it from the table.

```
create table [FreeIDs] (
  [ID] int, 
  [order] uniqueidentifier not null default newid() primary key);
insert into [FreeIDs] ([ID]) values (11111),(11112),...,(99999);

to get a free ID:

    with cte as (
      select top(1) [ID]
      from [FreeIDs] 
      order by [order])
    delete cte
    output deleted.ID;
```

The persisted predeterminer order speeds up generating new IDs.

BTW, if you're tempted to 'optimize' the table and go by a numbers table:

```
with Digits as (
    select Digit 
    from (
        values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), 
            (6), (7), (8), (9)) as t(Digit)),
Numbers as (
    select u.Digit + t.Digit*10 +h.Digit*100 + m.Digit*1000+tm.Digit*10000 as Number
    from Digits u
    cross join Digits t
    cross join Digits h
    cross join Digits m
    cross join Digits tm)
select top(1) Number 
from Numbers
where Number between 11111 and 99999
and Number not in (
    select ID 
    from Students)
order by (newid());
```

just don't. The requirement to randomize the set is a performance killer and the join to eliminate existing (used) IDs is also problematic. But most importantly the solution fails under concurrency, as multiple requests can get the same ID (and this increases as the number of free IDs is reduced). And of course, the semantically equivalent naive row-by-painfully-slow-row processing, like your original code or Kaf's answer, have exactly the same problem but are also just plain slow. It really worth testing the solution when all but one of the IDs are taken, watch the light dim as you wait for the random number generator to hit the jackpot...

Comment: Nice Idea , But I don't prefer that .
cause may be in the future i increase number to the random number For Example (make it 6 Digits Instead of 5)

Comment: when you want to add more IDs just insert them into the FreeIDs table. 6 digits, 10 digits, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: So much Thanks
This really convinced me , I Will apply this As soon as possible :)

Comment: How come it doesn't matter? if it is 9 digits, lower & upper are 111 111 111 - 999 999 999 you are inserting 888 million records.

Comment: @Kaf: Yes, if you expect 888MM students you start with 888MM free IDs and then you slowly transition to 888MM student records and 0 free IDs.  Storing 1B rows is not exactly unheard of in databases, *that's what thy're designed to do*.

Comment: @RemusRusanu you don't need to have 888M students to have 9 digit student number. OP does not say `st_num identity(1,1)`.